# How to create a zip or tar from GCP VM Instance to GCP Storage Bucket

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to create a compressed backup file from my /var/www VM Instance on GCP and save it to a GCP Storage bucket. I'd prefer to use SSH but was told to use this command using gcloud shell console:

gsutil cp -r /var/www/ gs://bucket-name

Using this command works but you first need to create the bucket and it copies each file. Instead of copying each file, I would much rather have one zip of tar file.

After I'm done, I need to pull or get that zip file from the bucket and extract it to a new VM Instance over writing the existing /var/www folders and keeping the same file and folder permissions. If anyone knows what command to use for that part of the process, it would be super helpful.

The first VM Instance which has the files I'm trying to backup is running Ubuntu 16.04. The new VM Instance is running Ubuntu 18.04.

The whole reason for doing this is because you cannot take a VM Instance that was originally created using Ubuntu 16.04, SSH then manually update it to 18.04. Actually you can update Ubuntu to 18.04, but once you've done that, you can no longer SSH back into that machine. Five GCP engineers have confirmed that. When I asked why we could no longer SSH into the updated VM Instance, I was told that once you update Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 manually using SSH, you wipe out the GCP Cloud SDK that came with the Ubuntu 16.04 original build. Not even installing the GCP Cloud SDK will fix the issue.

The only way around this problem is to create a brand new VM Instance using Ubuntu 18.04, which you can SSH into. Then to copy your data living in /var/www from the old machine to a GCP Storage Bucket, then to copy the data from that bucket into the new VM Instance.

Any help or advice on which commands to use either using gcloud shell or better yet, SSH - would be much appreciated.

Comment: You simply want to copy the /var/www directory of your VM right to a new VM but you can't SSH into the first one right?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do what you want.

**If you want/have to use a bucket** "in between" to store the `/var/www` directory then its easier to do it with [gcloud cp](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) command.

In this case it's best to `tar` the directory:
`tar -cvf webarch.tar /var/www/` and then copy it to your destination bucket, then to the target VM and `untar` it.

**If you don't have to use bucket** you can transfer the files with `scp` directly from one VM to another.

Here's how a [syntax of `scp`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) looks like:

`$ scp -r /local/directory/ username@to_host:/remote/directory/`

It will copy entire directory structure along with file permissions.

SCP also work well with [SSH keys](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/metadata/sshKeys) so you can use the ones you already have or [create one](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys) for this task.